# How to uninstall older versions of libcrypro library

Tags: c++, dll, linker-errors, libssl, libcrypto

I am trying to link the Unified Automation c++ OPCUA Stack to my project, but I am getting the warning :

`libcrypto.so.1.1, needed by libuastackd.so, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.0.0`

Followed by the error:

`:-1: error: libuapkicppd.a(uapkicertificate.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'OPENSSL_sk_num@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'`

From the command prompt, ldconfig on the shared libraries returns:

```
craig@craig-B250-HD3P:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libssl
        libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
        libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
        libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
        libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
craig@craig-B250-HD3P:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libcrypto
        libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
        libcrypto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
        libcrypto++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto++.so.6
craig@craig-B250-HD3P:~$
```

Can I safely delete `libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64)` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`?

Comment: Is it safe depends on whether anything else relies on it. For those, most certainly, there will be other applications using them. Does the external static lib reference the symbolic link? If so, then you can re-direct it to the version you want it to point to. This may break other applications though.

Comment: These look like system libraries (user installed libraries are conventionally installed in `/usr/local/lib`) and so should be uninstalled using your OS's package manager, it probably wont let you though as they'll be required dependencies of other packages.